# Why is an alkyne substituent on benzene is electron withdrawing, but alkane and alkene are electron donating?

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

Hammett constants for alkyls/vinyls/etc. are all negative (i.e. toluene), and my understanding is that they donate electrons through inductive/resonance effects.

However, ethynylbenzene has a positive Hammett constant, and I am unsure how to rationalise this in terms of induction/resonance (or whatever other effects that might be responsible for this).

Comment: Bonds from alkynyl group to the ring have mor $s$ orbitsl character, lowercl electron energy level, therefore effectively more electronegative.

Comment: Basically electronegativy of a -radical is kind of directional, to be sensed along the bond direction.